# combining one column using join with condition

Tags: php, mysql

Hello sql pros please help me i am stuck here .

I need to get those id combination if condition match like for these entries

```
(3, '', 'Gi', 'Blue', 'Male', 'Adult', 'Absolute', '2016-02-09 14:45:35', '2016-02-09 14:45:35'),
(4, '', 'Gi', 'Blue', 'Female', 'Adult', 'Absolute', '2016-02-09 14:45:35', '2016-02-09 14:45:35')
```

After query i would get result

```
3,4
```

but for the first row it dont have female section i want that too

something like

```
2
3,4
..
.
..
```

I have table structure like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_divisions` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `division_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `experience_level` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `gender` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `age_level` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `weight_class` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `modified` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


INSERT INTO `wp_divisions` (`ID`, `name`, `division_type`, `experience_level`, `gender`, `age_level`, `weight_class`, `created`, `modified`) VALUES
(2, '', 'Gi', 'Black', 'Male', 'Adult', 'Absolute', '2016-02-09 14:45:35', '2016-02-09 14:45:35'),
(3, '', 'Gi', 'Blue', 'Male', 'Adult', 'Absolute', '2016-02-09 14:45:35', '2016-02-09 14:45:35'),
(4, '', 'Gi', 'Blue', 'Female', 'Adult', 'Absolute', '2016-02-09 14:45:35', '2016-02-09 14:45:35')
```

So i doing this query

```
SELECT IF( (
t1.ID = t2.ID
), t1.ID , CONCAT_WS(  ',', t1.ID, t2.ID ) ) AS DVID
FROM wp_divisions AS t1
JOIN wp_divisions AS t2
ON (t1.division_type = t2.division_type
AND t1.experience_level = t2.experience_level
AND t1.age_level = t2.age_level
AND t1.weight_class = t2.weight_class
AND t1.ID != t2.ID)
GROUP BY DVID
```

Comment: Do you need the output in csv format?

Comment: Are you trying to manually build a JSON string directly out of your SQL Query??

Comment: Will the `name` field always be empty?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen no i just want to get those value as combination if found male female section is one of them is not available then single value like here for first row dont have female data so itt will show

2
then second row 
3,4
because having male female section

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen name is a extra field i forget to delete so please ignore that

Comment: If you are please [look at the manual for `json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and save yourself a LOT of PAIN

Comment: Do you need the result as `3, 4` or could it be two records one for `3` and one for `4` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be trying to do this

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID) as DVID,
       division_type,
       experience_level,
       age_level,
       weight_class
FROM wp_divisions
GROUP BY division_type,
       experience_level,
       age_level,
       weight_class
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dfc382/5)

Comment: amazing thank you so much i think i have to learn more . very simple query you wrote.

Comment: Yeah GROUP_CONCAT is magic, you can add a GROUP_CONCAT(gender) too if you like up to you

Comment: i will again i am thankful of your help. you made my day thanks once again